# Как сделать чтобы не дублировать код в JS?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы не дублировать этот код:

```
var showError = function(el) {
  el.parentNode.classList.remove('error');
  el.parentNode.classList.add('success');
  el.nextElementSibling.InnerHTML = element.dataset.error;
}
var showSuccess = function(el) {
  el.parentNode.classList.remove('error');
  el.parentNode.classList.add('success');
  el.nextElementSibling.InnerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: var a=b=function(){...}

Comment: @DNS, функции разные действия выполняют

Comment: йопте, `var a=b=function(el,msg){...} `

Comment: @DNS, а что поменялось-то? у тебя _a_ и _b_ - одна и та же функция, соответственно выполняют _одни и те же_ действия. А требуется выполнять разные

Comment: Разные? Одни и те же для разного параметра..

Comment: @DNS, конечно разные, в вопросе в одной функции innerHTML присваивается значение атрибута, в другой присваивается пустая строка.

Comment: Тут не чем не помочь, если у вас только два значения, то так всё и останется. А там где больше, там уже можно пофестивалить

Comment: Меня одного смущает `InnerHTML`?

Comment: @Other, совсем чуть-чуть )

Comment: Сейчас весь ДжаваСкрипт тяжело вздохнул... Он же не зря называется функциональным языком! Юзай функции. Это их первое призвание вообще, избавлять код от повторений.

Comment: @VostokSisters, ваши комментарии, как всегда, излишне эмоциональны :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Зачем использовать функции для выполнения программы?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536861/%d0%97%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function getClassSwitcher(classOff, classOn, getErrorMsg) {
  return function(el) {
    el.parentNode.classList.remove(classOff);
    el.parentNode.classList.add(classOn);
    el.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = getErrorMsg();
  };
}

const showError = getClassSwitcher('success', 'error', () => element.dataset.error);
const showSuccess = getClassSwitcher('error', 'success', () => '');
```

Вариант попроще:

```
function toggleClasses(el, on, off) {
  el.classList.remove(off);
  el.classList.add(on);
}

const showError = function(el) {
  toggleClasses(el.parentNode, 'error', 'success');
  el.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = element.dataset.error;
}
const showSuccess = function(el) {
  toggleClasses(el.parentNode, 'success', 'error');
  el.nextElementSibling.innerHTML = '';
}
```

Comment: зачем msg делать функцией?

Comment: Чтобы взять актуальное значение свойства, а не его копию на момент объявления функции

Comment: @vp_arth, быстро убери функцию с msg) Она там явно ни к чему

Comment: ага, а если оставить одну функцию, то вполне сойдет и обычным параметром

Comment: Ну да, параметр не копируется.

Comment: @Yuri, нет, в его варианте _к чему_, иначе в момент вызова showError - неизвестно значение атрибута

Comment: Блин, вы же не знаете, логику появления этого dataset.error. Не умеете вы рефакторить) Ничего не должно поменяться.

Comment: @vp_arth, не должно и не может - разные вещи. Не удивлюсь, если _element_ это очередная описка и должно было быть _el_

Comment: @vp_arth, а что за элемент *el*? Где он объявлен?

Comment: Это всего навсего аргумент функции, мой юный друг